# Can MSSQL CDC be used to capture old committed transactions?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, transactional-replication, change-data-capture

I can successfully capture change data from mssql CDC by issuing the query

`cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_capture_instance ( from_lsn , to_lsn , 
 '<row_filter_option>' )`

Here, `from_lsn` is the min_lsn(oldest uncommitted transaction) which I can obtain from the Database.

But I have an already committed old transaction which I want to replicate and so I obtained LSN for one of its rows and tried to issue the above query using the obtained LSN (from_lsn) which failed with the following error message

`Failure in executing queries  SQLException;ErrorCode : 313;SQLCode : S0003;SQL Message : An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ ...`

Is it possible to capture past changes from MSSql ? If yes, some guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Did you include all three arguments, or just the from_lsn?  Based on the documentation it looks like you have to include all three.

Comment: "If the specified LSN range does not fall within the change tracking timeline for the capture instance, the function returns error 208 ("An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes.")."

Comment: @TonyHinkle Can we replicate operations which were done before CDC was enabled on the table?

Comment: I highly doubt it.  I would be shocked if you get a definitive answer from anyone other than Microsoft support.  If you didn't have change tracking enabled, it doesn't seem like it would, "fall within the change tracking timeline for the capture instance"  Documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-all-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017